# Hibernate Multiple Join with a common table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm, hibernate-annotations

I came across a very particular scenario of a nested join query in Hibernate that should be fairly straightforward, but I'm having trouble narrowing down the data set.

I have a table structure like the following:

```
top                bottom             common
------------       ------------       ------------
id                 id                 top_id 
...                ...                bottom_id
...                ...                common_value
lastUpdated        lastUpdated        date_added
```

The goal is to query it so that I get an object with the following structure:

```
top: 
{ "id": 1, 
  "lastUpdated": "2016-05-01",
  ...
  "bottom" : [ {
     "id": 1
     "lastUpdated": "2016-01-01",
     ...
     "values": [ {
         "top_id": 1,
         "bottom_id": 1,
         "common_value": "abc",
         "date_added": "2016-05-15"
     } ]
  } ]
}
```

To do so I have these relationships:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "top")
public class Top {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    //...other fields...
    private Date updatedOn;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "common",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "top_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bottom_id")
    )
    private Set<Bottom> bottomSet;

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "bottom")
public class Bottom {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    //...other fields...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bottom_id")
    private Set<Common> values;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "common")
public class Common {

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "top_id", column = @Column(name = "top_id") ),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "common_value", column = @Column(name = "common_value", length = 32) ),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "date_add", column = @Column(name = "date_added", length = 19) ),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "bottom_id", column = @Column(name = "bottom_id") ) })
    private CommonId id;

}

@Embeddable
public class CommonId {

    private Integer top_id;
    private String common_value;
    private Date added_date;
    private Integer bottom_id;

}
```

What happens is that the resulting structure contains all of the values liked to the bottom_id, which is too many results.  How can I make it so that the bottom join for the common_values is bound to both the bottom_id and the top_id?

Ideas greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved --

The relationships did not change, but instead of querying all of the top items, I created the following HQL to associate the ids:

```
FROM Top t 
INNER JOIN FETCH t.bottomSet b 
INNER JOIN FETCH b.values v
WHERE t.id = :topId AND v.id.top_id = :topId
```